# Not getting records all columns from firebase database in c# razor pages

Tags: c#, firebase, razor, razor-pages

Actually, I am displaying the User data after the user has signed in, in the dashboard panel. But only getting the first and last name.
I debugged the code and it gives all other values null. But in the database all the columns are filled with record.

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whvtp.jpg)

Now here is the code, that I am using to get Data from database::

```
  public static User User 
        { 
            get 
            {
                
                return GetUser().Result;   
            } 
            set 
            { 
                if(value != _user)
                {
                    _user = value;
                }
            } 
        }

        public async static void Init(IJSRuntime js)
        {
#if Debug
HostURL = "http://localhost:5001/"
#endif
            jsRuntime = js;
            Module = await js.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "/js/bundle.js");
        }

        public async static Task<User> GetUser()
        {
            try
            {
                if (_user == null)
                {
                    var response = await jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("VerifyData");
                    var jsonResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(response);
                    var newuser = new User();
                    newuser.UID = jsonResponse.uid;
                    newuser.Token = jsonResponse.token;
                    response = await API.VerifyGetUser(jsonResponse.uid, jsonResponse.token);
                    jsonResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(response);
                    newuser.FirstName = jsonResponse.firstName;
                    newuser.LastName = jsonResponse.lastName;
                    newuser.ProfilePicURL = jsonResponse.profilePicURL;
                    newuser.Email = jsonResponse.email;
                   
                    _user = newuser;
                }
                return _user;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Main.Log.Log($"GetUser: {ex}", "ERROR");
            }

            jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("RemoveVerifyData");
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: Which properties are null that you think should have data? And what is the content of `response` here? Does it have the data you need? Have you stepped through the code and debugged it?

Comment: The Properties like ProfilePicUrl have url of image but it is showing null
The content of response is 
FirstName
Last name
Email 
ProfilePicUrl

I also Debugged there in Response 
Only fetching Email and Names
Not ProfilePicUrl

Comment: But what is the content of `response`?

Comment: The content of the response is
.......
" FirstName
 Last name
 Email 
ProfilePicUrl"
..........
 I also Debugged there in Response Only fetching.....
 "Email and Names.......
 Not ProfilePicUrl"